# Using value of variable as variable name for urlVariable in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3

I have the next code

```
var uv:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

//lot of them in an array
var variable:String = "mode";
var value:String = "easy";

uv.<variable_value> = <value_value>;
```

It's like using the value of variable as the variable name. How can I achieve this?

Edit: The next code represents what I need as result

```
uv.mode = 'easy';
uv.category = 256;
..
..
```

Where the variables `mode` and `category` are values of other variables.

Using php would be something like this:

```
$next = 10;
$var  = 'next';
echo ${$var}; //10
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you want ( because of the question formulation )

but i'm using URLVariables like this:

```
import flash.net.URLVariables;
import flash.net.URLLoader;

var urlVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables ();

// setting the values with names
urlVariables[value_name_1] = value_1; // value_name_* is a string, value_* is anything you need, Number, String, Array, Object etc...
urlVariables[value_name_2] = value_2;
urlVariables[value_name_3] = value_3;

// and now for the loading
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader ();
loader.data = urlVariables;
```

Comment: Your solution works great!. Thanks. I edited my question posting some examples.